# How to use coordinates search bar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, wgs84

When using coordinates search bar in QGIS, it sends me to a completely different location. The GPS coordinates style is 37.381096, 14.561191 and the project is set to EPSG: 3857 with OpenLayers basemap. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EPSG 3857 is a projected coordinate system (Web Mercator). Your coordinates appear to be Geographic, try with EPSG 4326 instead